# Using Python to search specific file names in (sub)folders

Tags: python-3.x, windows, search, directory

I'am trying to make a file searching, Python based program, with GUI. 
It's going to be used to search specified directories and subdirectories. For files which filenames have to be inserted in an Entry-box. 
while I'am fairly new to python programming, I searched the web and gained some information on the `os` module.

Then I moved on and tried to write a simple code with `os.walk` and without the GUI program:

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk( 'Path\to\files'):
    for file in files:
       if file.endswith('.doc'):
        print(os.path.join(root, file))
```

Which worked fine, however... `file.endswith()` Only looks to the last part of the filename. 
The problem is that in the file path are over 1000 files with .doc. And I want the code to be able to search **parts** of the **file name**, for example "**Caliper**" in filename "**Hilka_Vernier_Caliper.doc**".

So I went on and searched for other methods than `file.endswith()` and found something about `file.index()`. So I changed the code to:

```
import os
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk( 'Path\to\files'):
        for file in files:
           if file.index('Caliper'):
            print(os.path.join(root, file))
```

But that didn't work as planned... 
Does someone on here have an idea, how I could make this work?

Answer (score 2):

You may use `pathlib` instead of the old `os`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob

BTW, `file.index` raises an exception if the name is not not found, so you need a try/except clause.

Another way is to use `if "Caliper" in str(file):`

Comment: thank you for your comment vpoulailleau, I'll dive in the pathlib :-)